# Usage of "insomnia"

Tags: meaning

In Swedish one would understand insomnia as a disease where you couldn't sleep night after night, but now I'm currently learning Chinese and they seem to mean (for 失眠) just having trouble sleeping one night.

That leads to a debate among my friends, what does insomnia in English actually mean? Can it be used for both? Is it correct to use it for both?

Comment: Hi Ragshi. [This definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insomnia) seems to clear up your quandary. Is there anything in that definition that needs further explanation?

Comment: In general, once medical conditions become part of the daily lexicon, they start to be used more loosely. So while schizophrenia  is a true medical condition, you might hear someone say *he's a total schizophrenic* when describing someone whose behavior seems erratic or crazy. *Insomnia* is similar - you'll hear it used by doctors in reference to a specific condition, as well as by people who are describing their friend who doesn't sleep very much but has no medical problem.

Answer (score 6):

*Insomnia* is the state of being unable to sleep. The point at which such a state becomes a condition requiring therapeutic treatment is more matter of medicine than of language, for *insomnia* is used both in general and specialist contexts. If you’re really looking for something more esoteric, there’s *agrypnia*, but I wouldn’t rely on many people knowing what it was.

Answer (score 2):

*Insomnia*, used in a serious way, even in general speech, commonly means a persisting problem of being unable to fall asleep, esp. over a prolonged period.

Where you do not want to be misunderstood for such a medical condition, it is preferred to say *difficulty in sleeping*, *unable to sleep well*, *unable to fall asleep*, or something similar.

Lately though, it seems to have become fashionable to use high sounding jargon in casual speech.